# vue js bar-chart gradient color not showing

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, chart.js, gradient, vue-chartjs

I'm using vue-chartjs for chart

This is my BarChart.js

```
import {Bar} from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  data () {
  return {
    gradient: null,
    gradient2: null,
    datacollection: {
    labels: ['January', 'February','March'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Data One',
        backgroundColor: this.gradient,
        data: [40,42,99]
      },                    
    ]}
   }
  },
 mounted () {
  this.gradient = 
  this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);  
  this.gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(250,274,50,1)');   
  this.gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(250,174,50,0)');


  console.log(this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d'));
  this.renderChart(this.datacollection, {responsive: true, 
  maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }
}
```

And this is my Vue for it

```
<template>
   <v-flex sm6>
      <bar-chart></bar-chart>
   </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
  import BarChart from './BarChart.js';
  export default {
     components: {
         BarChart
     },
    data() {
        return {
            datacollection: null
        }
    },
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

But I can't see the gradient, so I did `console.log` for `this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d')` and it is referencing the bar-chart correctly but the fillstyle is not canvasgradient it is showing

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D

canvas:canvas#bar-chart

fillStyle:"#000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can not reference data properties inside data properties in vue.js

```
data: () => ({
 data1: '1',
 data2: this.data1
})
```

This will not work tho.

You can put your datacollection directly inside the `renderChart()` method and then add the gradient. Or try to use computed properties